# Divergence of $\sum_{n=1}^{+ \infty} \dfrac{x^n}{\sin(\pi \alpha n)}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

- $ x \geq 1$
- $\alpha \notin  \mathbb{Q}$
- $u_n=  \dfrac{x^n}{\sin(\pi \alpha n)}$

We want to prove that $S_r=\sum_{n=1}^{r} u_n$ diverges.

---

My attempt :

- $x^n \to \infty$
- $v_n= \sin(\pi \alpha n) \not \to 0$

It is obvious. How to prove it ? How to write a neat proof ?
Suppose that $v_n \to 0$ then

$ \forall \epsilon ,\exists N, \forall n, n>N  \implies |v_n| < \epsilon $

so $\forall \eta \quad \exists N , n>N \implies  \pi \alpha n < \eta [\dfrac{\pi}{2}]$,

$ n \alpha < \eta [\dfrac{\pi}{2}]$. I should see a contradiction. Or I can use the Cauchy criterion ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$|\frac {x^{n}} {\sin (\alpha \pi n)}| \geq |x^{n}|\geq 1$. Hence, $\frac {x^{n}} {\sin (\alpha \pi n)}$ does not tend to $0$ and this implies that the series is divergent.

Irrationality of $\alpha$ is only used to say that the terms of the series are all well defined!.